# Drop down menu's not saving using Custom Meta Boxs in WordPress

Tags: metabox, dropdown

I am playing with custom meta boxes within WordPress and when trying to modify a drop down menu and saving the option it doesn't save.

If I use the default template it saves the option fine.

```
case 'select':
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
echo '<option value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option['name'], '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
break;
```

Below is my modified version to allow 3 drop menus to be displayed:

```
case 'champbans':
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '_team1ban_1" id="', $field['id'], '_team1ban_1">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option1) {
echo '<option value="', $option1['value'], '_team1ban_1"', $meta == $option1['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option1['name'],  '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '_team1ban_2" id="', $field['id'], '_team1ban_2">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option2) {
echo '<option value="', $option2['value'], '_team1ban_2"', $meta == $option2['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option2['name'], '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '_team1_3" id="', $field['id'], '_team1_3">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option3) {
echo '<option value="', $option3['value'], '_team1ban_3"', $meta == $option3['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option3['name'], '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
break;
```

There are no errors being displayed and I can not spot the error after spending the past 2 hours looking at it. Any help or guidence is much appreciated.

Comment: could you post the rest of the code to give us some context? What is `$field`, for example? What is `$meta`?

Comment: Here is the full metabox code - http://pastebin.com/hzPuxsFM

The code I referenced starts at line 369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, the problem is that when you save the post meta, it's using a name that doesn't exist as you've added `'_team1ban_1` etc, but the code you've linked to looks for inputs named `$fields['id']`.

If you want to use the linked framework, I suggest you add them as separate fields. (i.e. three separate `select` boxes). Exactly how to do that falls out of the scope of this site, but a quick look at the pastie, it seems you'll want to add three arrays to the `fields` (see line 43 for example).

Comment: It was me just trying to cut a corner I think, I just wanted all the selects side by side instead of underneath each other. I have an idea to amend the table that is created for the metabox to work position the elements.